# Android developer console takes ages to update?

Tags: android, console

I released an application yesterday to the Android market, however I've hit a few issues when updating my app and tracking information via the developers console. First of all, when I update my app (either the APK or just information about it), the information seemingly takes a very long time to actually hit the market. Is this normal, or is it just because my app is new?

The other issue I'm having is that the developer console is telling me I have 0 downloads, when I know for a fact that isn't true. Furthermore, a friend told me he had rated/commented but the console is only showing 1 rating/comment, which is from someone else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only ans to your question is YES IT CAN DELAY. Sometime it can lead upto or more than 5-6 hours before you see your changes in the market.

The actual time taken to see the update on the devices can differ too b/w various platforms like 1.5, 2.2.2 etc.

So dont worry give it sometime and then check it. It will eventually update....Still better than Apple where it takes around a week.

Answer (score 2):

The number of downloads also take a while to update.  Frequently, they seem to be updated in "bursts" - ie. you will see all  your stats jump.

The updates for stats are not real time.  It would be a good idea to implement your own analytics (there are a variety of free options) if you would like more fine grained or real time stats.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look in to this.

Answer (score 1):

From what I am observing for last 7-8 months, Statistics are updated at interval of 24 hours.
For last one month, Console is updated daily around 2-4 pm IST for me.